# Is it possible to content may change, but still hashcode returns same value for a Node in xml

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am getting different children sometimes, for an xml node for single execution of program at different debugs, but still hashcode is same.Will it possible to be like this?

Is there any way how to know and when my xml node data being changed?
Please help on this?

Comment: `return 1` is a valid `hashCode()`. The hash code for an `Object` being the same does not indicate anything more than that - you cannot draw any assumptions about whether it is `equals` or not.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about `org.xml.dom.Node` and its subclasses like `org.xml.dom.Element`, these do not override the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods. That means they do the same as `Object.equals()` - which means the hash code depends only on the Java object identity, and doesn't change with the object's content. This effectively makes equals() useless for nodes (you don't even get a guarantee that the same node is always represented by the same Java object). DOM provides two methods for comparing nodes: `isSameNode` and `isEqualNode` - but neither of them provides a corresponding hash code function.

Lousy design, yes. Frankly, I don't know why anyone still uses DOM. There are much better alternatives available, like JDOM2 and XOM.

Comment: Yes, I understood that java object did not change,but content changed.How do i know when the content got changed?

Comment: I think you will have to do it the hard way. Walk the tree to compute some kind of checksum.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

All a hash code promises is that it is *always* the same if the content hasn’t changed. However, it does not promise that it will *always* change when the object changes. In fact, it *cannot* promise this, since objects are arbitrary size and a hash code is of fixed size. Once the object size exceeds than the hash size, you can no longer bijectively map the hash to the objects and there are at least 2 objects with the same hash.